# Cannot remove error "Conflict with another plugin which overwrites jQuery" from wordpress site

Tags: jquery, errors

I am troubleshooting a WordPress site and often when loading a page, as a visitor or admin, an error box pops up with that says "Conflict with another plugin which overwrites jQuery". After researching I found that WordPress version 5.5 does not work well with older versions of themes and plugins. However after updating or deactivating any plugins that caused errors, the error popup persists. I also found a plugin called "Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" that was supposed to suppress the error for website users but this does not help as well. How would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I don't think that error message is from WordPress core. Which plugin specifically is generating it? But you said you had solved the problem with all the plugins?

Comment: @Rup the theme customizr and another minor plugin for a font. The errors in the console view mode saying which ones are gone after i updated, but the error pop up on the website for users is still a problem.